# Calling glewInit() causes main function to not be called

Tags: c++, glfw, glew

I'm attempting to use GLFW and GLEW. Currently my code works, and I see a window with triangles:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "constants.h"

int main(void) {
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit()) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "Window", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    // if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    //  fprintf(stderr, "failure");
    //  return -1;
    // }

    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
    while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f(1, 0);
        glEnd();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window); /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works. However, when I uncomment the lines:

```
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failure");
    return -1;
}
```

The program exits silently. I confirmed with a breakpoint that the `main` function is not even being called. If it helps, here is my compilation command:

```
g++ -g main.cpp -I\glfw-3.3.2\include -I\glew-2.1.0\include -L\glfw-3.3.2\lib-mingw-w64 -L\glew-2.1.0\lib\Release\x64 -lglfw3 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -luser32 -lshell32 -lglew32 -o main.exe
```

I can't figure this out for the life of me. I'm calling `glewInit` after making the OpenGL window, I'm importing `glew` before `glfw`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Crash before main is either because of static initialization or dynamic libraries.

It seems you are on windows, in that case `glew` release files contain two libraries `glew32.lib` and `glew32s.lib`.

You are linking against the non-static one, try `-lglew32s`. The first one is just a stub that will search for .dll, usually located in `glew/bin` folder, you would have to copy it to the working directory with `main.exe`. Remove `GLEW_STATIC` if you choose to go this way.

To prevent future errors, add `glewExperimental=GL_TRUE;` somewhere before `glewInit`. It enables OpenGL 3.3+ functions on some drivers.

As for why is it working now, the whole reason for existence of extension loading libraries in the first place is that the default drivers include only OpenGL 1.x functionality. All newer functions must be loaded directly at run-time from `.dll` drivers supplied by your GPU using `dllopen()` and `GetProcAddress()` which is exactly what these libraries do for you. That is why most newer functions are actually implemented as macros (wrapping the function pointer). That said, you are not using any new functions (you really should), so everything is working fine.

Comment: Using `-lglew32s` gave me a bunch of errors like `undefined reference to `__imp_wglGetProcAddress'`. I think glew is more trouble than it's worth, and I'm just going to use glad. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @multitaskPro Not sure about it, you do link `opengl32`. Yes, I also strognly recommend `glad`, one header, one source and I never had any problems with it.